# File Upload Conditional

Tags: php, if-statement, file-upload

I have an html form with some text and file inputs that submits to a PHP page. I want to error check the image file input but only if they choose to include one. Is there a way to check if there's an uploaded image file? I included my attempt below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if ($_FILES['image'])
{ 
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0)
    {
        echo 'Problem: '; }}
        switch ($_FILES['image']['error'])
        {
            case 1: echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize.';
                break;
            case 2: echo 'File exceeded max_file_size.';
                break:
            case 3: echo 'File only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case 4: echo 'No file uploaded.';
                break;
            default: echo 'cannot upload.';
                break;
        } 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not seem to be working?

Comment: When I don't upload an image file and submit, `$_FILES['image']` is stilled passed as true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as none.

That is: testing the $_FILES element will always return true. You should test the file size and temporary name elements instead.